# Horizontal and vertical recyclerview parsing json data in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, arraylist

[See sanpshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChYXa.png)

```js
jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONObject resultObj = jObject.getJSONObject("result");
                    


  for(int i = 0; i < firstproducts.size(); i++) {

                           try {
                               title = firstproducts.get(i).getString("category");
                               categoryIcon = firstproducts.get(i).getString("icon_img");
                               Log.e("For I","Value : "+title);
      for(int j = 0; j < secondproducts.size(); j++) {
                                   if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(secondproducts.get(j).getString("category"))){
                                     
  categoryIcon = secondproducts.get(j).getJSONObject("info").getString("img");
                                       

          JSONArray products=null;
     products = firstproducts.get(j).gptJSONArray("Products");                          if(products!=null) {
         
             for (int k = 0; k < products.length(); k++) {
                                               
                                             
  JSONObject jsonObj = products.getJSONObject(k);

                                             
          content = jsonObj.getString("description");
       points = jsonObj.getString("points");
       imageUrl = jsonObj.getString("image");
                                           
                                       
         secondarraylist.add(new ChildModel(content,points,rating,imageUrl));
              }                         
}
   mainarraylist.add(new MainModel(title,categoryIcon,secondarraylist));
                                     finally i set this above main arraylist to recyclerview adapter
------------------------------- ---------
                                       
Mian Model class as below -child model inside 3 string values will be there.

public class MainModel {
    String title;
    String categoryIcon;
    private List<ChildModel> ChildItems;

    public MainModel() {
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getCategoryIcon() {
        return categoryIcon;
    }

    public void setCategoryIcon(String categoryIcon) {
        this.categoryIcon = categoryIcon;
    }

    public List<ChildModel> getChildItems() {
        return ChildItems;
    }

    public void setItems(List<ChildModel> ChildItems) {
        this.ChildItems = ChildItems;
    }
}
---------------------------------------
      Main adapter       
      
      
      public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private final Context mContext;
    List<MainModel> maindata;

    public MainAdapter(Context mContext, List<MainModel> ProductList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.maindata=ProductList;
    }


    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.product_list_store, parent, false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);

    }

    public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final TextView title;
        public final ImageView categoryIcon;
        public final ImageView leftArrow;
        public final ImageView rightArrow;
        public final View categoryDiver;
        private ChildAdapter horizontalAdapter;
        private RecyclerView horizontalList;
        private LinearLayoutManager llm;


        public ProductViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            Context context = itemView.getContext();
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_textForHeader);
            categoryIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_Iconimageview);
            leftArrow = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.product_leftside_arrow);
            rightArrow = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.product_rightside_arrow);
            categoryDiver = view.findViewById(R.id.product_Divider_view);
            horizontalList = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_layout);
            llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            horizontalList.setLayoutManager(llm);

            horizontalAdapter = new ChildAdapter(context);
            horizontalList.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.title.setText(maindata.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.horizontalAdapter.setData(maindata.get(position).getStoreItems()); // List of Strings
        holder.horizontalAdapter.setRowIndex(position);
        holder.leftArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("left");
                if (holder.llm.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() > 0){
                    holder.horizontalList.smoothScrollToPosition(holder.llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() - 1);
                }
            }
        });

        holder.rightArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("right");
                holder.horizontalList.smoothScrollToPosition(holder.llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() + 1);
            }
        });

        if(position == maindata.size()-1)
            holder.categoryDiver.setVisibility(View.GONE);

  }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       //return 0;
        return maindata.size();
    }

}
-------------------------------------------
  
  ChildAdapter

public class ChildAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    private List<ChildModel> childdata;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private int mRowIndex = -1;

    public ChildAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setData(List<ChildModel> data) {
        if (childdata != data) {
            childdata = data;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    publindex;
    }

    private class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final TextView content;
        public final TextView rating;
        public final TextView points;
        public final NetworkImageView img_item;
        public final ImageView img_rating;


        public ItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_item_title);
            rating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_rating);
            points = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_points);
            img_item = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_item_imageView);
            img_rating= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_rating);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.store_category_item, parent, false);
        ItemViewHolder holder = new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {

        ItemViewHolder holder=(ItemViewHolder)viewholder;
        holder.content.setText(childdata.get(position).getContent());
        holder.points.setText(childdata.get(position).getPoints());
        holder.rating.setText(childdata.get(position).getRating());

        holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  childdata.size();
    }
}
```

I am doing a project with horizontal and vertical recyclerview same like a play store. I have done all the designs like 2 adapters and 2 model class.

The problem is I parsed json and set all the data to 2 array list so all the data come to horizontal adapters. how to set horizontal values from arraylist according to below heading thats dynamic.

This is my API: bikes, cars, trucks; I need to set this data vertical  recyclerview heading and inside products array that is horizontal recyclerview:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you the approach-->Get all child json in the main array-->then in each of these json object get the products jsonobject and set them accordingly

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. exactly my problem is i parsed all the child data to array list and finally i set to mail arraylist so i got the output in  horizontal same all the child datas are comes all the vertical recyclerview.      Please share with me your code exactly json parsing with set to arraylist and finally set to adapter. plz send your code with my mail id (prasanthjune15@gmail.com) or post in this page. once again thanks for the comment.

Comment: actually i cant understand how your list will look like. ie which childs are set as header and which in horizontal,......can u give me a raw diagram for that?

Comment: exactly my problem is in my api bikes ,cars and trucks inside all the products array values  are coming together in horizontal, i mean Products[1],Products[8] and Products[2] are coming together bec i thing thats is in arraylist but i dont know how to split and add to recyclerview vertical adapter .  i have combained horizontal adapter inside vertical adapter please see my code.